# Padding does not work as expected in android

Tags: android, android-layout

padding does not work as expected in custom ViewGroup

Hi:

My layout have the following structure:

```
RelativeLayout(with padding)    
    MainView(ViewGroup)
```

And the **activety_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.testandroid.MainView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainView:**

```
public class MainView extends ViewGroup {
    public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet as) {
        super(context);
        addView(new MyView(context, null));
    } 

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        for (int i = 0, len = getChildCount(); i < len; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.layout(l,t,r,b);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyView:**

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
    public MyView(Context contex, AttributeSet as) {
        super(contex, as);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        refresh();
    }

    private void refresh() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        synchronized (holder) {
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                try {
                    Paint p = new Paint();
                    p.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, p);
                } finally {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        refresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

Now, this is what I got now:

[image]

As you can see, the viewgroup I created `MainView` has a background of `green`.
And `MainView` add a `MyView` dynamically whose background is black here.

Now, the problem is that what the `MyView` have a padding relative to `MainView`? Because I want it take all the space of `MainView`, that's to say, the `greed` should be invisible.

Why?
But

Comment: set padding to child view and check it once.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Apply padding to your child view instead of applying to relativelayout.

Comment: `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.testandroid.MainView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>` And I got this:http://i.imgur.com/ebeQDug.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you layout your children, it needs to be relative to your position.

To fill yourself you would do `child.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this ...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"


tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.example.testandroid.MainView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you want the padding?? on the dot or some other place??

Comment: Just like the layout_main.xml shown, I want the `RelativeLayout` have four paddings (left,right,top,bottom). It has nothing to do with the subview.

Comment: It seems that people misunderstand me. Well, I will update my post.